# Hide header and footer using Custom CSS

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I am trying to hide the header and footer from a specific page on my website. I am using a theme I downloaded online. The specific page I am trying to hide is http://ai-home.com/dsme/

I installed a custom CSS plugin so that I can customize the CSS on this page. I inspected the page element and can see that I am most likely trying to hide the

```
div id="header-space" and div id="footer-outer"
```

After reading online I think the code should be

```
.page-id-5321 .site-header, .page-id-5321 .site-footer {
  display: none; 
}
```

or

```
.page-id-5321 .site-header-space, .page-id-5321 .footer-outer {
  display: none;
}
```

When I publish, I do not see any changes to the page. I am not a developer so I want to make this edit as easily as possible without it affecting the rest of my website.

EDIT:

tried some suggestions and was able to fix most of the problem, but now I am stuck with a big grey bar on the bottom but I can't find it via inspect element.

EDIT#2: So the CSS looks like this right now, but still stuck with a grey bar on the bottom

```
#header-outer { display: none;}
#header-space { display: none;}
#footer-outer { display: none;}
```

Comment: #header-outer { display: none;} should do the work

Comment: thanks! that seems to have done the trick. so I have added:

#header-outer { display: none;}
#header-space { display: none;}
#footer-outer { display: none;}

but now I am still stuck with the grey bar on the bottom and I can't seem to find it when I inspect element. thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

Use the visibility property as hidden.
Like [     visibility:hidden    ]
In your header class/id.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by this?

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code for removing header-outer, header-space  and footer-outer

```
 .page-id-5321 #header-outer, .page-id-5321 #header-space, .page-id-5321 #footer-outer {

      display: none;
    }
```

Comment: yes, so i have tried the code and seem to have been able to remove most of what i want. but i am still getting a grey bar at the bottom that i can't find through page inspection/element

Answer (score 0):

I think if you use wordpress, in your specific page can use other header or/and other footer.
Change

```
 get_header();
```

to

```
get_header('<other header file>');
```

same with footer

Answer (score -1):

Try it

```
<div id="header-space" class="hide">xyz</div> and <div class="show" id="footer-outer">abc</div>
```

csscode:

.hide{display:none;}
.show{display:block;}

If you need to hide a block/section then just add class:hide to HTML OR for showing use class name show like mention above.

Hope it will work. Revert if it is not.

Answer (score -1):

For grey bar solution

```
#footer-outer #copyright, body {
    border: none!important;
    background-color: #f8f8f8!important;
}
```

By changing the color of footer you can use the same background.

Comment: i added this in addition to what I had earlier but still couldn't get rid of the grey bar  


`#header-outer { display: none;}
#header-space { display: none;}
#footer-outer { display: none;}
#footer-outer #copyright, body {
    border: none!important;
    background-color: #f8f8f8!important;
}`

Comment: Try this in css.          html, body {
    background: #f8f8f8!important;
}